# Swagger UI encoding error in .Net Core Web Api

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, swagger-ui

I'm currrently using swagger in a .Net Core API project but the documentation page generated by swagger is having encoding issues :

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this encoding issue? I tried looking for a place to configure the encoding but didn't find it.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(swaggerVersion, new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = swaggerVersion,
        Title = "Validação de telefones",
        Description = "API de validação de números de telefone utilizando somente dados internos.A api utilizado dados..."

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was the encoding of `Program.cs` file.
I was using Visual Studio 2022 and it's default encoding is `Western Europe` not `UTF-8`.
I followed the instructions in [this link](http://www.liangshunet.com/en/202003/567276536.htm) to make Visual Studio change the enconding it saved the file with.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your Swagger dependency. [The bug was fixed](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/commit/4aa63c7d4861727e84309ebb875cf57ea4f772ed) by adding `charset=utf-8` to the response's `Content-Type`. So, try the latest Swagger version and let us know if this helped to solve the issue.

Comment: Swagger version was 6.2.3 and I updated to 6.5 but it did not improve. Still got the enconding issue.